# Windows 7 Update wants to update an updated application

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Windows Update wants to keep installing an update that I have manually installed. How do I stop Windows update from alerting me to install this update.

Is there anyway that i can delete this from the update manager? or tweak the update manager to understand that this software has been updated, without uninstalling and reinstalling the software.

Also the update manager keeps wanting to install language packs that were already installed, this is very annoying as these are false updates anyway to bypass this?

Comment: Language packs are optional, they are not mandatory. You have to agree to install them, so it shouldn't be a major issue. If you don't want them, you can just hide them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the update and choose 'Hide this update' you can shift click on the language packs to hide them as well.